# Create a separate log in JBoss Management Console Runtime Log Viewer

Tags: xml, logging, jboss, redhat

**I need a separate log to be created in the Red Hat EAP Console Runtime Log Viewer.**
This because my server hosts two projects and both print their logs in the default "server.log".

This is my log4j.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" >
<log4j:configuration>
   <appender name="C" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
      <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%-5p,%d %r,%c{1},%t] %m%n" />
      </layout>
   </appender>
   <appender name="F" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}${file.separator}myProject.log" />
      <param name="Append" value="true" />
      <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB" />
      <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%-5p,%d %r,%c{1},%t] %m%n" />
      </layout>
   </appender>
   <root>
      <priority value="INFO" />
      <appender-ref ref="C" />
      <appender-ref ref="F" />
   </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: Let me make sure I got this right. You want to separate your projects (assuming you mean applications deployed on EAP) logs from JBoss EAP server logs?

Answer (score 1):

You have couple of options that can be utilized as part of management:

1. Use [logging profiles](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Logging+Configuration#LoggingConfiguration-LoggingProfiles).
2. Create a file handler for each application and assign a category as explained [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/How+To#HowTo-HowdoIlogmyapplicationsmessagestotheirownfile%3F)

You can also copy your [own logging.properties file in your application packages](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/How+To#HowTo-HowdoIuselog4j.propertiesorlog4j.xmlinsteadofusingtheloggingsubsystemconfiguration%3F) but then you wont be able to manage them centrally since it;s outside standalone/domain XML and set as [per deployment](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Logging+Configuration#LoggingConfiguration-PerdeploymentLogging).

Comment: Do note that using a configuration file in your deployment (per deployment logging) will not work with the log viewer. Only handlers defined on the logging subsystem will work with the log viewer. This does include logging profile handlers as well.